# Can I do Appium inspector connected simulator without error code 65

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-inspector

I had started a session between appium server and simulator(at xcode).
But xcodebuild failed with code 65

xcodebuild error message:
[debug] [W3C]
[debug] [W3C]     at quitAndUninstall (/usr/local/Cellar/appium/1.22.3/libexec/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:588:15)
[debug] [W3C]     at /usr/local/Cellar/appium/1.22.3/libexec/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:623:11
[debug] [W3C]     at wrapped (/usr/local/Cellar/appium/1.22.3/libexec/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:60:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at retry (/usr/local/Cellar/appium/1.22.3/libexec/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:43:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at retryInterval (/usr/local/Cellar/appium/1.22.3/libexec/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:70:10)
[debug] [W3C]     at /usr/local/Cellar/appium/1.22.3/libexec/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:603:7

---

[debug] [iOSSim] The simulator has '0' bundles which have 'WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner' as their 'CFBundleName':
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] No WDAs on the device.

I have kwnown that appium inspector connected with simulator does not need webAgentDriver. It isn't true?

In concolusion,

1. A simulator must need a WebDriverAgent? not for only a real device?
2. What is webDriverAgent? I think that it only let appium control iOS devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using xcode 14 we need to have appium 2 and appium inspector installed to be able to access the app

1. Make sure you have node 16.16, if you don’t you can install nvm and use it to install multiple versions of node on the machine, you can fine [NVM here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
2. Install Appium 2 using: `npm install -g appium@next`
3. Once Appium is installed run `appium -v` to confirm that you have version > 2
4. Install XCUITest driver: `appium driver install xcuitest`
5. Install UIAutomator2: `appium driver install uiautomator`
6. Run `appium driver list` to confirm that both drivers are installed
7. Install Appium Inspector: can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/releases), download the latest version.

Comment: I was finally done it due to downgrade Xcode 13 version!!
thank you! have a good day :)